# Error loading classifier from jar file - Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

Am trying to run load the classifier/model(english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser) from  the Stanford NER project.This file is in RAR format in the classifiers folder in project.But am getting the following error:

> Error loading classifier from jar file (most likely you are not
>   running this code from a jar file or the named classifier is not
>   stored in the jar file)

I have checked the path.Its correct.Also check with the gz extension.But not getting the result.I had run the same code few months back in jdk 1.6.Now am compiling same using jdk 1.5.
The classifier is stored in the folder and also am not running the code from JAR file.
Also tried extracting and giving that file name.But still the same error. 
Please guide me.

Comment: Can you list which jar files are in your classpath? Also, Stanford NER requires Java v1.6+.